# Excel function to find "depth" of string expression?

Tags: excel, algorithm

I have an algorithm in Python which basically helps find the "depth" of a function as such:

```
f(a) has a depth of 1
f(g(h(a,b,c),d)),e) has a depth of 3
```

The pseudo algorithm is such:

```
Run through all the characters from left to right
create a variable "depth"
for each open parenthesis increment depth
for each closing parenthesis decrement depth
At the end, the depth of the expression was the max value taken by the variable depth.
```

I was wondering if such logic was possible to achieve in Excel without using VBA.

Comment: can't you just count the number of "(" in the string?

Comment: won't work. F(g(),h(),i(),j(),k()) has a depth of 2, but the count of "(" will return 6

Comment: Now I get it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following *UDF()*

```
Public Function Depth(r As Range) As Long
    Dim v As String, CH As String
    Depth = 0
    v = r.Text
    kount = 0

    For i = 1 To Len(v)
        CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
        If CH = "(" Then kount = kount + 1
        If CH = ")" Then kount = kount - 1
        Depth = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(kount, Depth)
    Next i
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=Depth(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

[image]

Comment: you rock, I had no clue we could define a UDF in Excel!

Comment: @Stephane  If you can code in any variation of **C** or **Java**, then coding in **VBA** will be a snap *(but maybe a little frustrating)*